# Define $f:\mathbb{Z}_n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_n$ by $f(x)=x^2$ For which $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is $f$ injective?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Note that by $\mathbb{Z}_n$, I mean the congruence classes modulus $n$. I am having trouble understanding what to do for this problem. For this, I do know the answer, but something is not clicking and making it obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $f(x)=f(-x)$ and so $f$ is injective only if $x=-x$ for all $x\in \mathbb Z_n$, which only happens for $n=2$.

Comment: According to the solution, this should also happen for $n=1$.

Comment: @Brian, right, but it is not common to consider $\mathbb Z_1$.

Comment: I think the largest issue in understanding this problem is myself not yet having a good intuition for what congruence classes represent.

Comment: Okay, does $x$ then represent individual congruence classes? I think I was interpreting $x$ as being an element of a congruence class, not one itself.

Comment: @Brian, both ways work because $f([t])=[t]^2=[t^2]$.

Comment: Wonderful! That clarifies it. Thank you kindly!